# how to create function for this code in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, function, uiview

I had written transition animation code for `UIView` but this code is use in multiple screen so all the time I am writing the same code but I want to create class or function so I can easily call this wherever required but I am new in iOS so please help me how to create function and calling in `UIView`..

```
CATransition *trans = [CATransition animation];
trans.duration = 0.5;
trans.type = kCATransitionPush;
trans.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
[trans setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

[self.container_view.layer trans forKey:nil];
```

thanks in advance

Comment: you should also consider adding it to a category if you are always using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create AppFunction class like this:

**1. Header File**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppFunctions : NSObject
    + (void) animateView:(UIView *)view;
@end
```

**2. Implementation File**

```
#import "AppFunctions.h"

@implementation AppFunctions
+ (void) animateView:(UIView *) view
{
  CATransition *trans = [CATransition animation];
  trans.duration = 0.5;
  trans.type = kCATransitionPush;
  trans.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
  [trans setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

  [view.layer addAnimation:trans forKey:nil];
}
@end
```

Now call Like this where you want by importing `#import "AppFunctions.h"`

```
[AppFunctions animateView:self.view];
```

Answer (score 1):

call this method like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];

[self animate:self.view];}
```

here is your funcation

```
-(void)animate:(UIView *)view{
CATransition *trans = [CATransition animation];
trans.duration = 0.5;
trans.type = kCATransitionPush;
trans.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
[trans setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

[self.container_view.layer trans forKey:nil];}
```

Comment: but i have a multiple view

Comment: you only need to import this file in every page where you want to use this funcation

Comment: like this #import "youfuncation.h" and then call this funcation like this [youfuncation animate:self.view];